# Apparent Negative free disk space and FreeBSD 12

Tags: freebsd, disk-space-utilization

Just curious as to what's happening here.  This is just a non-prod VM that I have at home.  Curious as to what leads to the 'negative' available diskspace.  This is FreeBSD 12 running under VMWare ESXi 7.

```
FreeBSD ssh1.rynhart.co.nz 12.0-RELEASE-p10 FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p10 GENERIC  amd64
[root@ssh1 /fixeddisk]# df -h
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/da0s1a     15G    6.5G    6.9G    48%    /
devfs          1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/da1s1a    901G    861G    -32G   104%    /fixeddisk
```

Comment: Potentially a duplicate - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276187/why-does-df-show-negative-available-space

Comment: Thank you @tilleyc - I think this is indeed the case.  Although this volume is UFS (i.e. not an EXT2/3/4 volume).  After your hint, I was able to find that UFS also has reserved space (default is set at 8%).

Comment: [root@ssh1 ~]# fstyp -l /dev/da1s1a
ufs

[root@ssh1 ~]# tunefs -o space /dev/da1s1a
tunefs: optimization preference changes from time to space
tunefs: should optimize for time with minfree >= 8%
tunefs: /dev/da1s1a: failed to open disk for writing